# Bazel build package not found

Tags: python, bash, tensorflow, package, bazel

I'm trying to run Tensorflow code downloaded from github tensorflow/models/adversarial_text, but running into a bazel build error. The error looks quite straightforward. But as I haven't used bazel very much before, I'd appreciate any ideas/suggestions about it. The error is below:

ERROR: /home/dasgupta/adversarial_text/BUILD:60:1: no such package 'adversarial_text/data': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '//:inputs'.

Inside adversarial_text/BUILD:(line 60 - that gives above error) is the following rule:

```
py_library(
    name = "inputs",
    srcs = ["inputs.py"],
    deps = [
        # tensorflow dep,
        "//adversarial_text/data:data_utils",
    ],

}
```

But I see that there is a directory called "adversarial_text/data" and inside adversarial_text/data/BUILD there's this rule too:

```
py_library(
    name = "data_utils",
    srcs = ["data_utils.py"],
    deps = [
        # tensorflow dep,
    ],
)
```

I tried adding

```
 visibility = ["//adversarial_text:__pkg__"],
```

right after the deps rule for data_utils, but that didn't solve the problem.

Any ideas what I might be missing here, or what I might need to set/change (environment vars?) to get this to work.

My config: bash on Ubuntu 16.04, Tensorflow 1.2, bazel 0.5 and python 2.7

Comment: Where is your WORKSPACE file located? It looks like aversarial_text is the root of your workspace.

Comment: That's correct. adversarial_text is the root of my workspace. The WORKSPACE file is located inside the adversarial_text directory.

Answer (score 1):

The visibility has to be `//:__pkg__` since `adversarial_text` is the root of your workspace. And you should try building `//:inputs`.

Answer (score 1):

So to summarize, this is what I did to make it work, after cloning the project.

1 Create "WORKSPACE" file in adversarial_text/

```
    touch WORKSPACE
```

2 Edit deps in adversarial_text/BUILD

```
py_library(
    name = "inputs",
    srcs = ["inputs.py"],
    deps = [
        # tensorflow dep,
        "//data:data_utils",
    ],
)

py_test(
    name = "graphs_test",
    size = "large",
    srcs = ["graphs_test.py"],
    deps = [
        ":graphs",
        # tensorflow dep,
        "//data:data_utils",
    ],
)
```

3 add visibility for data_utils in adversarial_text/data/BUILD

```
py_library(
    name = "data_utils",
    srcs = ["data_utils.py"],
    deps = [
        # tensorflow dep,
    ],
    visibility = ["//:__pkg__"],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed now, running the code no longer requires bazel as of https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/3414